# how to retrive custom data from database from specific column in laravel php

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table users in database

id, name, users_type

there are multiple types of users_type like Admin, Sub Admin, Unsigned, Normal User

I want to get All Types of users_type But Not Admin user.

Comment: have you tried doing sql directly to the database? just sql query. without eloquent or any.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eloquent Model then

```
$users = User::where('users_type', '!=', 'Admin')->get();
```

Using Query Builder

```
$users = DB::table('users')->where('users_type', '!=', 'Admin')->get();
```

check this for query builder https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries and for Eloquent you can look this https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent

Answer (score 0):

```
$users = User::where('users_type','<>','Admin')->get();
```

You want to get result for equals to then no need add `=`

If you want to get only one user then use `first()` insted of `get()`